# .forEach is not a function on fromArray angular

Tags: angular, foreach, formarray

I am working on a requirement where I have to loop through 'formArray' controls defined in component.ts file to set the validations on form submit. I am getting an error like ".forEach is not a function" Mycode is below:

component.ts

```
ip_addresses_arr: any;

this.companyForm = this.fb.group({
   company_ip_addresses: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({
    id: 0,
    start_ip: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern("^([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})$")),
    end_ip: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern("^([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})$"))
  })]),
});
```

My forEachloop on formArray is:

```
saveCompanyInfo() {
  this.ip_addresses_arr = this.companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses');
  this.ip_addresses_arr.forEach(eachfield => {
    console.log("each field",this.ip_addresses_arr);
    if(eachfield.start_ip != "" && eachfield.end_ip == ""){
      console.log("coming inside end_ip is empty");
      eachfield.end_ip.setErrors({'incorrect': true});
      eachfield.end_ip.markAsTouched();
    }else if(eachfield.end_ip != "" && eachfield.start_ip == ""){
      console.log("coming inside start_ip is empty");
      eachfield.start_ip.setErrors({'incorrect': true});
      eachfield.start_ip.markAsTouched();
    }else{
      eachfield.start_ip.setErrors(null);
      eachfield.end_ip.setErrors(null);
    }
  });

  if (this.companyForm.valid) {
    -----------------
    -----------------
  }
}
```

My problem is it was saying **.forEach is not a function**. Can anyone please explain me whats wrong in the code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a linting issue, typescript and the editor complains about this because a `formInstance.get('controlName')` returns an Abstract control. You will have to tell the them that the control you received is a FormArray, you can do this by doing:

```
this.ip_addresses_arr = this.companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses') as FormArray;
```

And you need to loop over the controls as.

```
this.ip_addresses_arr.controls.forEach()
```

And you are not accessing the controls correctly

```
saveCompanyInfo() {
  this.ip_addresses_arr = this.companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses') as FormArray;
  this.ip_addresses_arr.controls.forEach(eachfield => {
    if(eachfield.get('start_ip').value != "" && eachfield.get('end_ip').value == ""){
      console.log("coming inside end_ip is empty");
      eachfield.get('end_ip').setErrors({'incorrect': true});
      eachfield.get('end_ip').markAsTouched();
    }else if(eachfield.get('end_ip').value != "" && eachfield.get('start_ip').value == ""){
      console.log("coming inside start_ip is empty");
      eachfield.get('start_ip').setErrors({'incorrect': true});
      eachfield.get('start_ip').markAsTouched();
    }else{
      eachfield.get('start_ip').setErrors(null);
      eachfield.get('end_ip').setErrors(null);
    }
  });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but its not working instead showing same error as `this.ip_addresses_arr.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Okay I tried it now it is showing a different error as `Cannot read property 'setErrors' of undefined` Please tell me how to set validations? as I already asked in the question

Comment: @PrasadPatel What you have asked in your question is you were not able to work on `forEach()` ;) Anyway check the edit

Comment: @PrasadPatel You can also access the values like: `eachField.value['start_ip']`

Comment: I tried both `eachfield.get('start_ip').value` & `eachField.value['start_ip']` but the condition is not satisfied hence going to `else` condition always.

Comment: @PrasadPatel If it doesn't satisfy the conditions then your form controls don't have appropriate values, what values do you have in your form? Try logging `console.log(this.companyForm.value)` and then analyze

Comment: okay the conditions is now satisfied but the form is getting submitted instead of showing the errors. As I am already setting validations using `setErrors()` method, so is the `form.valid` condition has to fail but it is set to success and the form is submitted.

Comment: @PrasadPatel That should not happen, please check what else changes your form status. I made a sample here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lqmqzs . As for me, I am done with this question, take it further yourself or ask another.

Comment: Okay the errors also showing now but the form is getting submitted. I use `if (this.companyForm.valid) {` condition to check if the form is valid, is it correct? or instead of using `setErrors` method do I have to use any other method to set validations?

Comment: Please check out my new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56088405/form-valid-always-true-angular