# form.valid always true angular

Tags: angular, validation, form-submit

I am working on angular form validation after user clicks on submit button, I am setting the required validations to empty fields on submit and also the error messages as 'required' showing in the form but after that the form is getting submitted. I have searched for solutions but did not get any one working.

**component.html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="companyForm" #formDir="ngForm" >
      <!-- company details -->

        <ng-container formGroupName="company_details">
          <div *ngSwitchCase="'company_details'">
            <div fxLayout="row wrap">
              <div fxFlex="50">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width w-80-p">
                    <mat-label>company name</mat-label>
                  <input matInput formControlName="name">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div fxFlex="50">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width w-80-p">
                    <mat-label>display name</mat-label>
                  <input matInput formControlName= "display_name">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container formGroupName="company_settings">
          <div *ngSwitchCase="'company_details'">
            <div fxLayout="row wrap">
              <div fxFlex="50">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width w-80-p">
                    <mat-label>website</mat-label>
                  <input matInput formControlName="website">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div fxFlex="50">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width w-80-p">
                  <!-- <input matInput placeholder="FISCAL START" value="January 2018"> -->
                  <mat-label>fiscal start</mat-label>
                  <mat-select formControlName="fiscal_start">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let fl of FiscalList | keyvalue" [value]="fl.key">
                      {{fl.value}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>

              <div fxFlex="50">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width w-80-p">
                    <mat-label>company contact</mat-label>
                  <input matInput  formControlName="contact_number">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div fxFlex="50">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width w-80-p">
                    <mat-label>faxe</mat-label>
                  <input matInput formControlName="fax">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div fxFlex="100">
                <h2 class="text-uppercase font-weight-900 font-size-18">Description</h2>
                <div fxfill fusePerfectScrollbar>
                  <quill-editor [style.display]="'inline-block'" [style.height]="'200px'" #description
                    formControlName="description">
                  </quill-editor>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngSwitchCase="'logos'">
            <div class="page-layout simple">
              <div class="logo-bg">
                <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxFill>
                  <div fxFlex="50" class="px-24 pb-24 text-center">
                    <h4 class="font-size-16 text-bold text-center mb-0">Company Logo </h4>
                    <span class="text-normal">500px X 300px</span>
                    <div class="file-upload-bg p-12">
                      <div class="text-center h-160">
                        <!-- <img src={{logo_path}} style="max-width:100%;height: 130px;"> -->
                        <img [src]="url" style="max-width:100%;height: auto;">
                      </div>
                      <div class="file-upload text-center">
                        <label for="file"> Choose file </label>
                        <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="file" formControlName="company_logo" 
                          (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div fxFlex="50" class="px-24 pb-24 text-center">
                    <h4 class="font-size-16 text-bold text-center mb-0">Social Media Logo </h4>
                    <span class="text-normal">500px X 300px</span>
                    <div class="file-upload-bg p-12">
                      <div class="text-center h-160">
                         <img [src]="url1" style="max-width:100%;height: auto;">
                      </div>
                      <div class="file-upload text-center">
                        <label for="file1"> Choose file </label>
                        <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="file1" formControlName="social_media_logo_path"  (change)="onSelectFile1($event)">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngSwitchCase="'locale_information'">
            <div fxLayout="row wrap">
              <div fxFlex="50">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-80-p">
                  <mat-label>Currency</mat-label>
                  <mat-select formControlName="currency">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let currency of currencyList | keyvalue" [value]="currency.key">
                      {{currency.value}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div fxFlex="50">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-80-p">
                  <mat-label>Date Format</mat-label>
                  <mat-select formControlName="date_format">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let df of defaultDateFormats | keyvalue" [value]="df.key">
                      {{df.value}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div fxFlex="50"> 
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-80-p">
                  <mat-label>Timezone</mat-label>
                  <mat-select formControlName="timezone">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let tz of timezone_list[userList.country_id]" [value]="tz.id">
                      {{tz.name}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div fxFlex="50">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-80-p">
                  <mat-label>Time Format</mat-label>
                  <mat-select formControlName="timeformat">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let tf of timeformat | keyvalue" [value]="tf.key">
                      {{tf.value}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngSwitchCase="'resume_inbox_config'">
            <mat-checkbox formControlName="resume_inbox_non_user" (change)="changeSelect($event)" > 
              All non users to send resumes
            </mat-checkbox>
            <br>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="companyForm.get('company_settings').get('resume_inbox_non_user').value" class="example-full-width w-40-p mt-12">
              <mat-label>Candidate Owner</mat-label>
              <mat-select formControlName="resume_inbox_contact_owner" multiple>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let eachc of candidateList" [value]="eachc">{{eachc.name}}</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
              <mat-error *ngIf="(companyForm.get('company_settings').get('resume_inbox_non_user').value && companyForm.get('company_settings').get('resume_inbox_contact_owner').errors?.required) ">
                Candidate Owner is required
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </ng-container>

        <div *ngSwitchCase="'billing_address'">
          <ng-container formGroupName="billing" >
            <!-- <form> -->
            <div fxLayout="row wrap" class="pl-28">
              <div fxFlex="50">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width w-80-p">
                    <mat-label>street</mat-label>
                  <input matInput formControlName="street">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div fxFlex="50">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width w-80-p">
                    <mat-label>city</mat-label>
                  <input matInput formControlName="city">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div fxFlex="50">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-80-p">
                  <mat-label>Country</mat-label>
                  <mat-select formControlName="country">
                    <mat-option value="">-- Select Country --</mat-option>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let country of objectValues(masterdatalist.countriesList)" [value]="country.id">
                      {{country.name}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div fxFlex="50">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-80-p">
                  <mat-label>State</mat-label>
                  <mat-select formControlName="state">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let state of masterdatalist.countriesStates[companyForm.get('billing').get('country').value]" [value]="state.id">
                      {{state.name}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div fxFlex="50">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width w-80-p">
                    <mat-label>zip</mat-label>
                  <input matInput formControlName="zip">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-container>
        </div>

        <div *ngSwitchCase="'ip_restrictions'">
          <div class="mb-20" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
            <span class="mr-12">
              Applicable to:
            </span>
            <div *ngFor="let user of companyForm.get('applicable_to').controls; let i = index" >
              <mat-checkbox class="mr-32" *ngIf="i === 0" [formControl]="user" [checked]="user.value === 1 ? true : false ">Recruitment Activities</mat-checkbox>
              <mat-error *ngIf="(user.touched || user.untouched) && !user.valid">
                Required
              </mat-error>
              <mat-checkbox [formControl]="user" *ngIf="i === 1" [checked]="user.value === 1 ? true : false " (change)="checkRecruitment($event);">HR Management</mat-checkbox>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div formArrayName="company_ip_addresses">
            <div *ngFor="let item of companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').controls; let i=index; let isFirst = first">
              <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">

              <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
                <div fxFlex="30">
                  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width" class="w-90-p">
                      <mat-label>start ip</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="start_ip" (blur)="checkStartEndIP($event.target.value,i,'start_ip')" >

                    <mat-error *ngIf="(companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').at(i).controls.start_ip.touched  || companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').at(i).controls.start_ip.untouched) && companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').at(i).controls.end_ip.valid && !companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').at(i).controls.start_ip.value ">
                      Required Start IP
                    </mat-error>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="((companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').at(i).controls.end_ip.dirty || companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').at(i).controls.end_ip.touched) && companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').at(i).controls.start_ip.errors?.pattern)">
                        Invalid Start IP
                    </mat-error>
                  </mat-form-field>
                </div>


                <div fxFlex="30">
                  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width" class="w-90-p">
                      <mat-label>End Ip</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName= "end_ip" (blur)="checkStartEndIP($event.target.value,i,'end_ip')">
                  <mat-error *ngIf="(companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').at(i).controls.end_ip.touched  || companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').at(i).controls.end_ip.untouched) && companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').at(i).controls.start_ip.valid && !companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').at(i).controls.end_ip.value ">
                      Required End IP
                  </mat-error>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="((companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').at(i).controls.end_ip.dirty || companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').at(i).controls.end_ip.touched) && companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').at(i).controls.end_ip.errors?.pattern)">
                    Invalid End IP
                  </mat-error>     
                </mat-form-field>  

                </div>


                <div fxFlex="30">
                  <div *ngIf="isFirst;then addfield else delete">
                  </div>
                  <ng-template #addfield>
                    <button mat-icon-button class="text-center" (click)="addItem()">
                      <mat-icon class="font-weight-900">add</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                  </ng-template>
                  <ng-template #delete>
                    <button mat-icon-button class="text-center" (click)="deletefield(i)">
                      <mat-icon class="font-weight-900 red-500-fg">delete</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                  </ng-template>
                </div>
                <ng-template #addfield>
                  <button mat-icon-button class="text-center" (click)="addItem()">
                    <mat-icon class="font-weight-900">add</mat-icon>
                  </button>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template #delete>
                  <button mat-icon-button class="text-center" (click)="deletefield(i)">
                    <mat-icon class="font-weight-900 red-500-fg">delete</mat-icon>
                  </button>
                </ng-template>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <ng-container formGroupName="login">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'login'">
          <div fxLayout="row wrap">
            <div fxFlex="50" fxFlexOffset="25" class="px-48">
              <div class="text-center">
                <h2 class="font-size-26 text-bold">Hello</h2>
                <p class="font-size-14">Please login to your account</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100-p">
                    <mat-label>email</mat-label>
                  <input matInput formControlName="login_email" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
                  <mat-icon matSuffix class="grey-700-fg">email</mat-icon>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100-p">
                    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
                  <input matInput formControlName="login_password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
                  <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" class="grey-700-fg cursor-pointer">{{hide ? 'visibility_off'
                    :'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
                </mat-form-field>
                <div class="text-right cursor-pointer">
                  <a>forgot password? </a>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center mt-12">
                  <button mat-flat-button color="primary"
                    class="px-60 py-4 font-size-14 text-bold btn-rounded">Login</button>

                </div>

              </div>


              <div class="mt-60 text-center">
                <button mat-flat-button class="font-size-14 text-bold grey-400-bg mr-20 px-12"
                  (click)="urlDialog()">URL</button>
                <button mat-flat-button class="font-size-14 text-bold grey-400-bg" (click)="embedDialog()">Embed
                  Code</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>

    </form>
```

**component.ts:**

```
ip_addresses_arr: any;

this.companyForm = this.fb.group({
id: [],
company_details: this.fb.group({
  name: [],
  display_name: []
}),
company_settings: this.fb.group({
  id: [],
  website: [],
  fiscal_start: [],
  contact_number: [],
  fax: [],
  description: [],
  company_logo: [],
  social_media_logo_path: [],
  logo_path: [],
  currency: [],
  date_format: [],
  timezone: [],
  timeformat: [],
  resume_inbox_non_user: [],
  resume_inbox_contact_owner: [''],
  logo: [''],
  original_logo: [''],
  social_media_logo: ['']
}),
billing: this.fb.group({
  id: [],
  street: [],
  city: [],
  country: [],
  state: [],
  zip: []
}),
company_ip_addresses: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({
  id: 0,
  created_by: 0,
  modified_by: 0,
  start_ip: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern("^([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})$")),
  end_ip: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern("^([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})$"))
})]),
  applicable_to: this.buildUserTypes(),
    login: this.fb.group({
    login_email: [''],
    login_password: ['']
  }),
});
```

**My form validation on submitting the form is:**

```
saveCompanyInfo() {
  this.ip_addresses_arr = this.companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses') as FormArray;
 this.ip_addresses_arr.controls.forEach(eachfield => {
  console.log("start_ip value - ",eachfield.value['start_ip']);
  console.log("end_ip value - ",eachfield.value['end_ip']);
  if( eachfield.value['start_ip'] != "" && (eachfield.value['end_ip'] == null || eachfield.value['end_ip'] == "" ) ){
    console.log("coming inside end_ip is empty");
    eachfield.get('end_ip').setValidators([Validators.required]);
    eachfield.get('end_ip').updateValueAndValidity();
    eachfield.get('end_ip').markAsTouched();
    console.log("eachfield.get('end_ip') after setErrors - ",eachfield.get('end_ip'));
  }else if( eachfield.value['end_ip'] != "" && (eachfield.value['start_ip'] == null || eachfield.value['start_ip'] == "" ) ){
    console.log("coming inside start_ip is empty");
    eachfield.get('start_ip').setValidators([Validators.required]);
    eachfield.get('start_ip').updateValueAndValidity();
    eachfield.get('start_ip').markAsTouched();
    console.log("eachfield.get('start_ip') after setErrors - ",eachfield.get('start_ip'));
  }else{
    console.log("coming to else");
    eachfield.get('start_ip').clearValidators();
    eachfield.get('end_ip').clearValidators();
  }
 });

 console.log("this.companyForm.valid - ",this.companyForm.valid);

  if (this.companyForm.valid) {
    -----------------
    -----------------
  }
}
```

**My browser console is**:

```
eachfield.get('start_ip') after setErrors
FormControl {...}
 asyncValidator: null
 dirty: (...)
 disabled: (...)
 enabled: (...)
 errors: {required: true}
 --------

 this.companyForm.valid -  true
```

As you can see above my formcontrol set to "required: true" and also the my **form.valid condition is setting to 'true' and the form is getting submitted automatically after clicking on submit button**. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Provide full code here https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular

Comment: how can I post full code. I can only post component.html & component.ts file code but what about the styles?

Comment: Add the code related to your html form here

Comment: @AngelaAmarapala I have added HTML code, please check the question once again.

Comment: @PrasadPatel Its quite difficult to tell the problem by looking at your code! I would suggest providing a stackblitz [with minimum code] where *I/we* can reproduce an issue.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I know my html code is little long but I tried adding code in stackblitz but it was asking me CSS also. So I was unable to add it. I have added my full form builder code in ts just now. Please check my html & JS code. **I somehow fixed the form submission by checking both conditions like** `if (this.companyForm.valid && this.companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').valid ) {` instead of only checking `form.valid` like earlier but I want the form to be stop from submission by using only `form.valid` It has to work according to Angular

Comment: @PrasadPatel Is that Provided regular expression behave correctly?

Comment: Yes It is working fine, checking the regular expression correctly. If I add this condition `this.companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').valid` to `form.valid` then it is working fine. So`this.companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').valid` showing the false correctly but I am wondering why the parent to it I mean the main `form.valid` not taking its child validation input and don't stop the form submission?  Please help.

Comment: @PrasadPatel somehow if you provide me with a stackblitz then will try

Comment: @PrashantPimpale You are right, as you asked this "Is that Provided regular expression behave correctly?" my regular expression is showing the error in the form but the form is getting submitted. that means, my `this.companyForm.get('company_ip_addresses').valid` becomes TRUE.

Comment: @PrasadPatel ok!